# Quotations about the power of simple ideas

Tags: soft-question, reference-request, big-list

I'm looking for quotations about how very simple mathematical ideas can be very powerful. I know of a few, but they're not quite what I'm looking for insofar as they contain criticism of other mathematicians, and I'm looking for quotations that are more unambiguously affirmative.

Two that are in the direction of what I'm looking for are:

1. *The very notion of a scheme has a child-like simplicity - so simple, so humble in fact that no one before me had the audacity to take it seriously. So ”infantile” in fact, that for many years afterwards, and in spite of all the evidence, for so many of my ”learned” colleagues, it was treated as a triviality.* – Alexander Grothendieck
2. *It is the snobbishness of the young to suppose that a theorem is trivial because the proof  is trivial.* – John Whitehead

Any better examples?

Comment: What is the motivation behind this? I mean *examples* abound. What is the specific purpose of collecting the quotations (the first one of which already annoys me; well I knew it before, but still I am reannoyed). Also at the very least this is a prime example for CW.  

Comment: Jonah: in case you are interested, the motto of the Ross program is "Think deeply of simple things."  

Comment: @ quid - I had forgotten to make the question CW (as well as big-list) and just did so. The reason that I'm asking about this is to find quotes to include in mathematical exposition for beginners. I can see how the first quotation would rub you the wrong way - as I said in the first paragraph of my question, the examples that I know of contain implicit criticism of other mathematicians, and I'm looking for quotations that get the idea across without being critical of others. 

Comment: @Patricia, when I was at the Ross program I had the impression the motto was a quotation from Gauss. 

Comment: Once I cast the final closing vote, I feel obliged to tell an anecdote at least. A young (at the moment of the story) mathematician visited S. Bernstein and talked to him for a couple of hours about some new exciting results in the theory of entire functions. In the end, Bernstein sighed and said "This is, of course, very nice but as far as I am concerned, the function $\sin z$ is still full of mysteries". 

Comment: "I have proved something difficult. I will now claim that it follows from a simple insight, so as to create an impression that I am blessed with inspiration without perspiration." YC, 2012

Answer (score 10):

Here is a quote from *[The Power of Mathematics](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~mackay/conway.pdf)* by John Conway.

> What I like doing is taking something
>   that other people thought was
>   complicated and difficult to
>   understand, and finding a simple idea,
>   so that any fool – and, in this case,
>   you – can understand the complicated
>   thing. These simple ideas can be
>   astonishingly powerful, and they are
>   also astonishingly difficult to find.
>   Many times it has taken a century or
>   more for someone to have the simple
>   idea; in fact it has often taken two
>   thousand years, because often the
>   Greeks could have had that idea, and
>   they didn’t. People often have the
>   misconception that what someone like
>   Einstein did is complicated. No, the
>   truly earthshattering ideas are simple
>   ones. But these ideas often have a
>   subtlety of some sort, which stops
>   people from thinking of them. The
>   simple idea involves a question nobody
>   had thought of asking.

Answer (score 5):

Imaginary numbers appear in algebra when we try to take square roots
of negative numbers.... Geometric interpretation consists in observing that
two consecutive rotations of the plane by 90 degrees around a fixed point
reverse the directions of the vectors. If we think of the 180-degree
rotation reversing vectors as the geometric counterpart of multiplication
of numbers by -1 reversing the sign, then we are inclined to accept the
90-degree rotation (of the plane containing the line of real numbers)
as the square root of -1.
 All this looks childlishly simple, why do mathematicians make such a fuss
around it? How can one dare to compare this plain idea to profound
philosophical pronouncements, such as "Cogito ergo sum" of Descartes?
But look (as my colleague David Ruelle once suggested) from another perspective.
"Cogito ergo sum" stayed unperturbed for more than three centuries,
like a monument, a Greek statue, a magnificent piece of art, impervious
to the flow of time, whilst the little speck of dust, the square root of -1,
have been growing and developing for hundreds of years in the minds of
mathematicians, geniuses like Cauchy, Gauss and Riemann, and turned into an evergreen intensely alive vibrant tree supporting in its branches our
sacred knowledge - quantum mechanics - ruling everything we see (and do not see)
in this world.

(Misha Gromov, Local and global in geometry, October 29, 1999.)

Answer (score 2):

[Atle Selberg (Interview, June 11, 1989, page 30)](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/DOCdev1.pdf):

> In some sense, I think those are probably the most important things, those that can be made simple.

Or, with one more phrase of context.

> There are other things in mathematics that may seem impossible to begin with, but after they have been done they seem very simple. In some sense, I think those are probably the most important things, those that can be made simple.